# Not able to perform Filter on Dynamics CRM "Opportunity" transaction type with estimatedclosedate

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I am using QueryExpression to generate the filter for the Dynamics crm filters and then passing that to the my CRM made service to retrieve the result.

```
QueryExpression queryCRM = new QueryExpression
                {
                    EntityName = SourceID,
                    ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(FieldSet),
                    Criteria = new FilterExpression()
                };
```

and then

```
queryCRM.Criteria.AddCondition(strFilterColumnName,ConditionOperator.On , strFilterValue);
```

Here i am not able to fetch the result can anybody help me to figure out the issue?
It doesn't work for "estimatedclosedate" other than this it works fine withe all other columns.

Note := Initially it seems like an operator issue so i used "ConditionOperator.On" , so it solved my issue for Incident but not for opportunity.

Need solution from the CRM experts out there.

Thank You.

Comment: can you edit your question to include the relevant part of the queryexpression?

Comment: ok..doing that.done.

Comment: @GuidoPreite you got my question.

Comment: What happens if you perform the same query in that Org using Advanced Find? If that works, take the FetchXml and plug it into your code to see if it works. If the Advanced Find works and the FetchXml works then call QueryExpressionToFetchXmlRequest passing in `queryCRM` to see what the difference is between the FetchXml that works and what your `QueryExpression` is generating as FetchXml. This should narrow down the issues for you.

Comment: can post some sample code for Advance Search?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is strFilterValue a string? Try and pass this parameter as a DateTime. It would help if you could post this section of code in it's entirety. Here's some sample code which demonstrates the use of filtering an opportunity by estimated close date.

```
        var estimatedCloseDate = DateTime.Parse("2014-10-07");
        Guid createdId = Guid.Empty;
        Entity matchingEntity = null;

        try
        {
            // Create a test opp
            var opp = new Entity("opportunity");
            opp["name"] = "Testing Date Filter";
            opp["customerid"] = new EntityReference("account", Guid.Parse("b9b0ed35-2a11-4fb6-a56f-5b8c04a3c1d1")); // A valid customer
            opp["estimatedclosedate"] = estimatedCloseDate;
            createdId = _service.Create(opp);
            Console.WriteLine("Created Id: {0}", createdId);

            // Create the filter expression
            QueryExpression queryCRM = new QueryExpression
            {
                EntityName = "opportunity",
                ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(true)
            };
            queryCRM.Criteria.AddCondition("estimatedclosedate", ConditionOperator.On, estimatedCloseDate);

            // Run the search and check for a match vs the record just created
            var results = _service.RetrieveMultiple(queryCRM);
            foreach (var result in results.Entities)
            {
                if (result.Id == createdId)
                {
                    matchingEntity = result;
                }
            }

            // Survey says... 
            Console.WriteLine(matchingEntity == null
                                ? "Matching entity not found!"
                                : "Matching entity found!");
        }
        finally
        {
            // Delete the created opp
            if (createdId != Guid.Empty)
            {
                _service.Delete("opportunity", createdId);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Still issue is alive...parsing is not helping.

Comment: Can you post more code? For example, where is strFilterValue coming from. Also make sure you take into account time zone's. If a value was entered in a particular time zone, it's possible that it is being read from a tz which see's that as being +/- a day.  Just make sure that the data you are looking for in crm actually exists. Also can you confirm that when you say "not able to fetch the result" you actually mean "i get no records" and not "i'm getting an error message"?