# Dynamics CRM Date filter is not working on Opportunity transaction type on Estimated Close Date

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011

I am using the Query Expression to filter the records i have on the client side.I am doing as follows,

```
    QueryExpression queryCRM = new QueryExpression
 {
  EntityName = SourceID,
  ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(FieldSet),
  Criteria = new FilterExpression()
  }

queryCRM.Criteria.AddCondition(_strFilterColumnName, ConditionOperator.On, strFilterValue);
```

where variables like Filter column is the name of the field and operator i used is "On" because i am filtering on Date column.

Interestingly this code works if i point to some other CRM and doesn't works if i point it to my test machine's CRM.

Can any one out there help me resolve this issue.

Thank You!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Not able to perform Filter on Dynamics CRM "Opportunity" transaction type with estimatedclosedate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26237511/not-able-to-perform-filter-on-dynamics-crm-opportunity-transaction-type-with-e)

Comment: right but no answer is coming and i need it urgently.

Comment: StackOverflow doesn't work in this way, you can't create a duplicate question just because your previous got no answers